# Can't install McAfee antivirus free

Tags: 12.04, antivirus

I bought a Dell Vostro 3546 laptop online with Ubuntu as a OS. They gave McAfee antivirus free but I can't install it, now I can't install my McAfee antivirus in my Ubuntu 12.04, they show that (dependency is not satisfiable libicu42 in ubuntu 12.04) but I don't know how to make it as I am new to ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

It's more than likely just a standard bundle the dealer has put together and shouldn't imply it's suitability for the OS supplied with the machine.

McAfee is generally for Windows OS and you probably don't need it for Ubuntu (see numerous other posts about the need for anti virus software on the Linux platform in these forums).

Just pop it in the bin or use the CD as a bird scarer tied to the branch of a tree with some string ;)